# Showing if these sets are finite, countably infinite or even uncountable

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am working on a few questions. I'm trying to see whether the following are finite, uncountable or countably infinite. Explanations using surjective and injective would help me understand at a deeper level.

1. $\{1/m \mid m ∈ \mathbb{Z}, m ≠ 0\}$
2. $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{N}$  (Real numbers - Natural numbers?)
3. $\{x \mid x ∈ \mathbb{N} \text{ and } |x-9| > |x|\}$ (no idea how to get started on this one!)
4. $4\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$

for **1** I think it is finite since the set of integers, $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable

for **2** I believe it is uncountable since $\mathbb{R}$ itself is uncountable

for **3** I have no idea where to begin

for **4** I guess this is the cross product of the set of Integers, not sure where to start for this either.

Comment: 1) If the set of integers is countable why would the set the recipricals of integers be finite?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  4) is probably a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: For $\#3$, just try some examples.  I think the pattern will become obvious.

Comment: @fleablood If reciprocals of distinct integers were identical, it could be possible. (Obviously not, though)

Comment: 2) You need to know what the cardinality of removing countable elements from an uncountable set results in. 3) If $x \in N$ then $|x|= x$ and $|x-9| = x-9$ if $x \ge 9$ or $|x-9| = 9-x$ if $x < 9$.  As $x-9 > 9$ is impossible this means $x < 9$.  SO this is the set of ally natural numbers where $x < 9$ and $|x-9| = 9-x > x$. 4) You need to know about the cartesian products of countable sets.

Comment: In #3, the set is a subset of $\mathbb N,$ and that tells you it cannot be uncountable.

Comment: "In #3, the set is a subset of N, and that tells you it cannot be uncountable. – " ... Also for significantly large values of $n$ we have $|n-9| = n-9$ and $|n| = n$ so the condition for large natural numbers would be $n-9 > n$ and that never happens.  So the integers in #3 can't be significantly large.  SO there is an upper limit to how large the element of #3 are.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $\Bbb Z$ and countable and there is a bijection between this set and $\Bbb Z$, this set is countable too.
2. By that argument, $\{0\}$ is uncountable, since it is $\Bbb R\setminus(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$. The set $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$ is uncountable since it is the complement of a countable set in an uncountable set.
3. That set is finite, since it is equal to $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
4. It's the Cartesian product of two countable sets, and therefore it's countable.

Answer (score 0):

Hints (no answers)

1. Consider $f: \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\} \to \{1/m | m ∈ \mathbb{Z}, m ≠ 0\}$ where $f(m) = \frac 1m$.

Is that a bijection?  If so $| \{1/m | m ∈ \mathbb{Z}, m ≠ 0\}| = |\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}|$.

2. You need to call an a theorem about what the cardinality of removing the a countable elements from an uncountable set.  Do you know the theorem I am referring to.
3. Well, what *is* $M = \{x | x ∈ \mathbb{N} \text{ and } |x-9| > |x|\}$

If $n = 59$ then $|n-9|= |59- 9| = |50| = 50$ and $|n|=|59| = 59$ and $|n-9|=50 < 59=|n|$ so $59\not \in M$.  And if $n = 3$ then $|n-9| = |3-9| =|-6| = $ and $|n|=|3| = 3$ and $|n-9| = 6>3 = |n|$ so $3 \in M$.

And $\pi \not \in \mathbb N$ so $\pi \not \in M$.  So what *IS* $M$ if we know $59$ is *not* in $M$, and $3$ *is* in $M$ and $\pi$ and $\text{Babar, the elephant}$ are not in $M$. What *is* and is not in $M$.

4. What is the cardinality of $4\mathbb Z$?  Of $2\mathbb Z$.  What do you know about that cardinalities of Cartesian products?

.....

More on 3:

$|x-9| = x-9$ if $x- 9 \ge 0$ and $|x-9| = 9-x$ if $x -9 < 0$.  And $|x|=x$ if $x \ge 0$ and $|x| = -x$ if $x < 0$.

So you have four cases

1. If $x -9 \ge 0$ and $x \ge 0$ then if $x-9 > x$ we have $x \in M$.
2. If $x - 9 < 0$ and $x \ge 0$ then if $9-x > x$ we have $x\in M$.
3. If $x-9 \ge 0$ and $x < 0$ then if $x-9 > - x$ we have $x \in M$.
4. If $x-9 < 0$ and $x < 0$ then if $9-x > -x$ we have $x\in M$.

those can be restated as

1. If $x \ge 9$ and $x \ge 0$ then $-9 > 0$ then $x \in M$.
2. If $x \le 0 < 9$ and $2x > 9$ then $x \in M$.
3. If $x < 0 < 9 \le x$ then if $2x > 9$ then $x \in M$.
4. If $x< 9$ and $x < 0$ then if $9 > 0$ then $x \in M$.

....

Note  only one of those is possible.